Dart SSE Server Source Event Error Flutter
have a problem with SSE dart.
Use Library, fetch_api or sse_client for get event of server.
if use web chrome with devtools, i see, that Eventstream handle it.
But dont recenter image description hereieve in Debug Console and dont’t handle any event.
void main() {
  var handler = {

    'play': (event) {
      print('Event: ' + event.event!);
      print('Data: ' + event.data!);
    },

    'stop': (event) {
      print("Stop");
    },

    'other': (event) {
      print("Other");
    },
  };

///GET REQUEST
SSEClient.subscribeToSSE(
method: SSERequestType.GET,
url: 'http://10.99.12.213:8000/stream',
header: {
// "Cookie":'jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDMyMTAyMzEsImV4cCI6MTY0MzgxNTAzMX0.U0aCAM2fKE1OVnGFbgAU_UVBvNwOMMquvPY8QaLD138; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 02 Feb 2022 15:17:11 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict',
"Accept": "text/event-stream",your text
// "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
}).listen((event){
print('id:' + event.id!);
    if(event.event! == "play"){
      print('Event: ' + event.event!);
      print('Data: ' + event.data!);
    }
    
  });

Python Server
@app.get("/stream_2")
async def stream(request: Request):
    client_ip = request.client.host
    print(f"Client {client_ip} connected to the stream")
    return StreamingResponse(waypoints_generator(), media_type="text/event-stream")



# Test SSE SERVER WORKING
# Test SSE client WORKING dart flutter
MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY = 1  # second
MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT = 15000  # milisecond

@app.get("/stream")
async def stream(request: Request):
    async def event_generator():
        datatest = {
            "url_video": "https://storage.yandexcloud.net/feedbackstorage/testmedia/testmedia.mp4",
            "name" : "video_name",
            "video_id": 123, 
            "autoplay": "false"
        }
        
        # for n in range(number):
        while True:
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                client_ip = request.client.host
                print(f"Client {client_ip} disconnected from the stream")
                break
            
            if event_generator():
                yield {
                    "event": "play",
                    "id": randrange(1,10),
                    # "retry": MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                    "data": datatest
                }
            await asyncio.sleep(MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY)
            # await request.("flush")  # Flush the buffer after each event
    response = EventSourceResponse(event_generator())
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/event-stream"
    response.status_code = 200
    response.listen_for_disconnect
    return response 

